# Elementary OS system setting for power has problem

Tags: release-freya, power

If I set Turn off screen when inactive  when plugged in then the same value is also in On battery. So I cannot set right for only when plugged.

This must be a bug either in my setup or in Freya.

Does any one know have to that is right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only settings affected by the *Plugged In* and *On Battery* buttons are those **below** them on the power settings dialog, not those above.

I recommend you post a feature request on the *switchboard-power-plug* [bug tracker](https://launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-power) if you would like additional plugged in / on battery functionality.